# Using a callback when interval finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a tree traversal program which animates the traversal using `setInterval`. While setInterval is running, I want to disable "run traversal" button so they can't keep running new traversals.

When the traversal finishes and interval is cleared, I want to re-enable the buttons. A stackoverflow answer suggested using callback to call `enableButtons` once the interval has finished...

`this.traverseNodes(nodesToDraw, aryList, e.target.id, this.enableButtons);`

```
 api.traverseNodes = function (nodesToDraw, dataStructureList, algType, enableButtonsCallback) {
         ...
        var myInterval = setInterval (function() {
                            if (i >= nodesToDraw.length-1) {
                                matrixTraversalRunning = false;
                                enableButtonsCallback(dsTraversalRunning, matrixTraversalRunning);
                                clearInterval(myInterval);
                            }
```

This works fine, but then thought... why do I need a callback? I can just call `enableButtons` directly after the interval finishes, as such:

`this.traverseNodes(nodesToDraw, aryList, e.target.id);`

```
api.traverseNodes = function (nodesToDraw, dataStructureList, algType) {
       ...
        var myInterval = setInterval (function() {
            if (i >= nodesToDraw.length-1) {
                self.enableButtons(dsTraversalRunning); //call function to enable buttons
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
            ...
```

From this, I am confused on when to use a callback. Is it necessary here?

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't necessary.

However, using the callback would allow you to use the same class for tree traversal on different pages with different layouts. For example, you might want to enable/disable three buttons on one page, and only one button on another page.

Here's an example:

```js
//First I'll create a fake tree class for performing work:
var FakeTree = function(size){
  this.size = size;
  
  //Create a fake method to simulate node traversal
  var _this = this;
  this.TraverseOneNode = function(){
    _this.size = Math.max(_this.size - 1, 0);
    return (_this.size == 0);
  }
}

//Now define function for traversal
function TraverseNodes(tree, callbackfn){
  var myInterval = window.setInterval( function(){
    if(tree.TraverseOneNode()){
      clearInterval(myInterval);
      callbackfn();
    }
  }, 500);
}


//Now define callbacks for the two button sets:
function button_one_callback(){
  //Enable button1
  $('#button1').removeAttr('disabled');
}

function button_two_callback(){
  //Enable button2, and buttonOK
  $('#button2').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#buttonOK').removeAttr('disabled');
}


//Button onclick functions:
function button_one_click(){
  //Disable button one
  $('#button1').prop("disabled",true);
  
  //Call "TraverseNodes", pass it a new FakeTree of size=5, and the callback for this button
  TraverseNodes(new FakeTree(5), button_one_callback);
}

function button_two_click(){
  //Disable button one
  $('#button2').prop("disabled",true);
  $('#buttonOK').prop("disabled",true);
  
  //Call "TraverseNodes", pass it a new FakeTree of size=10, and the callback for this button
  TraverseNodes(new FakeTree(10), button_two_callback);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Traverse Tree 1" onclick="button_one_click()" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Traverse Tree 2" onclick="button_two_click()" />
<input type="button" id="buttonOK" value="OK" />
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: OK, I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

use this example from w3schools:

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

links for more examples:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp